# Material-UI Slider not drag when loading component from a switch

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on functionality where there is a set of radio buttons that change the state and determines which components should be active.   I think I am close and the values all get set as they should but the slider will not slide, you have to click it in to position.   I have a sandbox of what I am talking about here :

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-banach-k1i4y?file=/src/Form.js

You will see that the radio reveals the appropriate slider.  If you click the TEST button you can see that the correct value gets set to the object.  I also added another Slider outside of the switch render method and you can see that works as expected.

Also here is the code I am using

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
    import {
      Radio,
      RadioGroup,
      FormControlLabel,
      FormControl,
      Typography,
      Slider,
      Button
    } from "@material-ui/core/";

    export default function CreateForm() {
      const defaultValues = {
        a: 0,
        b: 0,
        c: 0
      };

      const [radioValue, setValue] = useState("");
      const [activity, setActivity] = useState(defaultValues);

      const handleRadioChange = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        setValue(value);
        setActivity(defaultValues);
      };

      const handleSlider = (name) => (e, value) => {
        setActivity({
          ...activity,
          [name]: value
        });
      };

      function RadioButtonsGroup() {
        return (
          <RadioGroup
            aria-label="group"
            name="group"
            value={radioValue}
            onChange={handleRadioChange}
            row
          >
            <FormControlLabel
              name="group"
              value="a"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="A"
            />
            <FormControlLabel
              name="group"
              value="b"
              control={<Radio />}
              label="B"
            />
          </RadioGroup>
        );
      }

      function test() {
        console.log(activity);
      }

      function RenderSwitch(radioValue) {
        switch (radioValue.value) {
          case "a":
            return <GetA />;
          case "b":
            return <GetB />;
          default:
            return <p>Select Radio</p>;
        }
      }

      function GetA() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
              A
            </Typography>

            <Slider
              value={activity.a}
              aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              step={10}
              marks
              min={10}
              max={120}
              name="a"
              onChange={handleSlider("a")}
              style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }

      function GetB() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
              B
            </Typography>

            <Slider
              value={activity.b}
              aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
              valueLabelDisplay="auto"
              step={10}
              marks
              min={10}
              max={120}
              name="a"
              onChange={handleSlider("b")}
              style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
            />
          </Fragment>
        );
      }

      return (
        <>
          <form noValidate onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <FormControl>
              <RadioButtonsGroup />
              <RenderSwitch value={radioValue} />
              <Button
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
                onClick={test}
              >
                TEST
              </Button>

              <Typography
                style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}
                id="discrete-slider"
                gutterBottom
              >
                One more to show how drag works here
              </Typography>

              <Slider
                value={activity.c}
                aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
                valueLabelDisplay="auto"
                step={10}
                marks
                min={10}
                max={120}
                name="c"
                onChange={handleSlider("c")}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the sliders' state change inside their own elements like so ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bell-rgy60?file=/src/Form.js)):

```
const SliderA = () => {
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setActivity(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        A
      </Typography>

      <Slider
        value={activity}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        step={10}
        marks
        min={10}
        max={120}
        name="a"
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: @Zac This is just one of MUI's weird behaviors. On the face of it, your code should work fine. In fact, if you simply copy and paste those slider elements directly into the return, they work. And yet if you render them inside their own elements, it acts weird; it sort of works. I ran into the same issue 6 months ago and the only thing I could find on is that sometimes MUI acts in mysterious ways.

Comment: Thank you, I am just learning react and appreciate the help.  MUI is being weird in different way with dropdowns so maybe posting another question here soon :)